# Why two elements on a page have the same ID?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

On a web page I see this at one point in the markup: (notice the id of the span)

```
<div id="UpdatePanel3">     
    <span id="Timer3" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
    <select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1" class="form-control" 
        size="2" onchange="navFromList(this.value);">
        <option value="12720">Blawblawblaw</option>
    </select>                                           
</div>
```

And down at the bottom in a CDATA section I see this (notice the uniqueID):

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._Timer, {"enabled":true,"interval":15000,"uniqueID":"Timer3"}, null, null, $get("Timer3"));
});
```

How can they have the same Id on the same page? I know it has something to do with AJAX (or at least partial page refreshes), but I don't understand it yet.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: You do know the difference between html and javascript I hope. Sys.Application refers to the span.

Comment: I only see one element with the id Timer3...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `$create` call creates an object of type `Sys.UI._Timer` and then attaches it to the span in the DOM tree. Note that the timer itself is not a DOM object, just a javascript one. It just has the same value of the uniqueID field as the DOM object's id, for convenience I suppose.

You can have as many javascript objects as you want created during the page lifetime, all having "id" or "ID" or "uniqueID" fields set to the same value. It does not directly relate to your DOM model, and does not conflict with it.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Making the uniqueID the same as another ID may have been convenient for them but sure confused me... a person seeing it for the first time.  I am trying to turn off the timer, but can't seem to get a handle on it. I try something like this `var timer3 = $find('<%= Timer3.ClientID %>');` but timer3 is always null.

Comment: @davecove, this is best fit for a separate question. Can you post a new one?